# Download Html + Blob image as text

Tags: javascript, blob, text, ms-word

On my VF page, I need to save to SF an html code with a signature represented as a blob (drawn with HTML5 Canvas) as a text file (preferably MS word).

Right now, I'm not sure if this should be accomplished on the server side (apex) or the client side (JS) - what do you think will be the best course of action?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35488280/4276413) solution but unfortunately, the downloaded file appears with the html tags and does not render the blob as an image.

See this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dq2oza36/2/).

Comment: Last time I tried doing something like this I couldn't find a way to get an blob image into a normal doc. It seemed to require the docx file format, which is more complicated to create. There might be a JavaScript library for it though.